# Difference between 見覚える / 覚える / 思い出す

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I saw this sentence in a show `見覚えあるけど` 
and I got confused with the differences between 見覚えある / 見覚える / 覚える / 思い出す?

I saw [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%A8-%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99-%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E3%81%84-whats-the-difference-of-oboeru-and-omoidasu) that explained the difference between 覚える and 思い出す but not the rest.

Comment: You wrote 覚える twice in the title and the body. Did you mean for there to be another word?

Comment: Am i think i ment 覚え,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`見覚えある` is used when you mention something you have seen before.

> この絵、見覚えある。
>   I have seen this picture before.

Since `見覚え` is a noun, there is no verb `見覚える`. So the formal form of `見覚えある` is `見覚えがある`.

Additionally, there is a similar expression: `聞き覚えがある`. It is used when you mention something you have heard or listened before.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw that there is 身に覚えがある, its when someone admits on crime right?

Comment: Very close. It is used to mention something you have done or experienced before. It is typically a bad thing, but not restricted to crime. Sometimes it's used to blame someone like the situation of a detective investigating a suspect. Sometimes it's used as rhetoric: `みなさんにも身に覚えがあるでしょうが ...`