# Nuances on the usage of 思い出す vs 覚える

Tags: word-choice, words

I'm aware that both can mean 'to remember', but is there a nuance on the usage of these words? or are they interchangeable?

Comment: This question has already been answered here https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/覚える-と-思い出す-の違い-whats-the-difference-of-oboeru-and-omoidasu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [「覚える」と「思い出す」の違い - what's the difference of oboeru and omoidasu?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/%e8%a6%9a%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%a8-%e6%80%9d%e3%81%84%e5%87%ba%e3%81%99-%e3%81%ae%e9%81%95%e3%81%84-whats-the-difference-of-oboeru-and-omoidasu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than a nuance. They mean two different things.

First of all, it’s important to note both are punctual verbs. 思い出す means “to recall” in the sense of bringing something back into one’s mind, and 覚える means “to memorize” in the sense of intentionally committing something into one’s memory.

Neither describes the state of remembering something. For that, you need to say 覚えている.